# MySQL restore dump from Azure Storage

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-blob-storage

Can we restore MySQL database from SQL dump file which is stored in Azure Storage as Blob/Fileshare directly without downloading it?

While using below command in powershell/cmd:

```
& cmd.exe /c "mysql --user=root --password=pass --protocol=tcp --host=dbname.mysql.database.azure.com --user=user@mysql --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 < https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/container/azure.sql"
```

I am getting **"The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"** error.

Comment: Was the below answer helpful for you?

Comment: I am looking for Mysql Db, below is suitable MS SQL